# Let user order images in an has_many_attached relation with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Is there a way to let user chose the order of images?

Let say we have a `Product` model with `has_many_attached :images`
And we want to let `user` chose the order of `images` (like with a drag and drop tool), for instance the first one will be profile image.

Do you recommand a model implementation for that usecase?

Comment: Is it something you expect to persist across visits? Then yes. You could add a column to images called `sequence`. I would avoid the word "order"  as the column name. The integer in `sequence` would allow `...images.order(:sequence)`

Comment: Yes I expect to persist

Comment: If you just want the first image to be primary, then you can add a boolean column `primary_image`, else adding the `sequence` column makes sense

Comment: The issue is that we can't add a column to ActiveStorage from the has_many_attached :images association

Comment: @VishalJain just no. If you add a boolean then you would have to add validations and constraints to ensure that there is only one primary image. Instead just add a column that contains the id of the primary image.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

ActiveStorage takes an approach to file uploads where you store all the data about attachments in a single repository instead of having separate tables per model or adding columns to the model. This is the tradeoff made to make it just magically work when you add `has_many_attached :images` to the model.

ActiveStorage is just an abstraction around storing the file somewhere so that you can later retrieve it. Don't confuse it with the "thing" which is the entity in your business logic.

If you're adding a bunch of business logic (custom ordering, captions, etc) to the uploads you should really create your own model that represent the entity in your specific domain and not monkeypatch your business logic into ActiveStorage.

For example a ProductPhoto as a higher level concept isn't actually the same thing as just the JPG file. Its a link to the file, captions etc.

```ruby
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :primary_image, class_name: 'ProductPhoto', 
                             optional: true
  has_many :product_photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_photos
end

# rails g model ProductPhoto product:belongs_to sequence:integer 
class ProductPhoto < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

Comment: Thanks, do you recommand a way to be sure that sequence is uniq, and that the first photo has a sequence = 1, and the second one = 2, and that if a photo is deleted, all next photos have their sequences -1 ?

Comment: Maybe I can use the gem https://github.com/brendon/acts_as_list for the ProductPhoto model

Comment: Yeah, I would take a look at the gem as there a re a lot of non-trivial problems involved. Ensuring the uniqueness is pretty simple - you just have a unique compound index on sequence and product_id.

Comment: Maintaining the correct order of the sequnce can probally be done in many ways. You could have a database trigger which updates all the rows with the same `product_id` using a CTE or subquery to get the RANK of the rows when ordered by sequence. I'm really just spitballing here though. This isn't something I have actually implemented.